# How to save and restore turtle-graphics draw parameters into/from a file?

Tags: python, save, turtle-graphics

Is it possible to draw something in Turtle, save the draw parameters in a file or db, exit the application and reopen it with the picture drawn so far?

Comment: It's possible, but there's nothing built-in to do it that I know of — so you would need to implement it yourself. This could be done by defining your own "wrapper" functions that saved information about each draw command and its parameters before executing it.

Comment: unfortunately bad for me, thanks for the input. And thanks for revising

Comment: Note I also did some general web searching, but found no existing third-party Python modules that did it, either. Actually I don't think it would be too difficult to implement — and suggest you should give it a try.

Comment: I will try and when I have done it I will come back

Comment: That's good to hear. You're allowed to post answers to your own questions here (after a certain amount of time) — and doing so would likely help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I have now solved my problem as follows:
since i'm still new to python, i'm still not quite comfortable with the wrapper function.
Graphics drawn with Turtle and saved as PNG every time I run through it. So now I have the overview where I am and how I have to continue, if I close the application

```
import turtle
from turtle import ScrolledCanvas, RawTurtle, TurtleScreen
from random import randint
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import time
root = Tk()
cnt = 0
canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800)
canvas.pack()

myPen = RawTurtle(canvas)
myPen.speed("fastest")

def drawTree(branchLen, t, size):
    global cnt
    cnt += 1
    makePicture(myPen, cnt)
    if branchLen > 5:
        if branchLen < 20:
            t.color("green")
        if size < 0:
            size = 1
            rsize = size
        else:
            rsize = size + 1

        myPen.pensize(size)
        tangle = 20
        t.forward(branchLen)
        t.right(tangle)
        drawTree(branchLen - randint(5, 15), t, size - 1)

        t.left(2 * tangle)
        drawTree(branchLen - randint(5, 15), t, size - 1)
        t.right(tangle)

        t.backward(branchLen)
        myPen.pensize(rsize)
        t.color("black")


def makePicture(myPen, cnt):
    nameeps = "tree.eps"
    ts = myPen.getscreen()
    ts.getcanvas().postscript(file=nameeps)
    saveImg(nameeps, cnt)

def saveImg(nameeps,cnt):
    image = "tree{}.png".format(cnt)
    canvas.postscript(file=nameeps, colormode='color')
    imgNew = Image.open(nameeps)
    imgNew.convert("RGBA")
    imgNew.thumbnail((2000,2000), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    imgNew.save(image, quality=95)

myPen.hideturtle()
myPen.penup()
size = 10
myPen.pensize(size)
myPen.goto(-50, -300)
myPen.pendown()
myPen.left(90)
drawTree(100, myPen, size)
root.mainloop()
```

This is just an example code I have tried around